# Hide the number of products on the shopping cart when it is empty

Tags: theming, 8, commerce

I copy the file "commerce-cart-block.html.twig" in my sub-theme. Currently it displays my shopping cart with the number of products inside.

I want that when there is no product in it, the shopping cart remains displayed and the number disappears.

How to do this ?

```
<div{{ attributes}}>
  <div class="cart-block--summary">
    <a class="cart-block--link__expand" href="{{ url }}">
      <span class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></span>
      <span class="badge">{{ count }}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
  {% if content %}
  <div class="cart-block--contents">
    <div class="cart-block--contents__inner">
      <div class="cart-block--contents__items">
        {{ content }}
      </div>
      <div class="cart-block--contents__links">
        {{ links }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not add an if around the  tag containing the {{ count }}?

since you are using Drupal 8, you can use [Twig filters](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/index.html). One way could be like below.

```
{% if count > 0 %}
    <span class="badge">{{ count }}</span>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks for the link, it works. I have a quick question, on drupal 7 it was not advisable to put PHP code in a custom block. On drupal 8 if I put twig code in a custom block, does this pose a security problem ?

Comment: @marsouin Twig is supposed to be more secure than the PhpTemplate used in Drupal 7. I would definitely as much as possible stay away from the raw filter. Here is a guide i used that provides good amount of information on Twig (https://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/new-theming-layer/twig.html). There are other links but this is a good summary of advantages and disadvantages.